# AutoSave a form inputs using jQuery + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

We would like to implement a web form that automatically saves content at regular intervals.Something similar to gmail/google docs auto save funcationality.

Can some one suggest how to implement this using ASP.NET MVC + jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jQuery Forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and an ASP.NET MVC action should do the job:

```
public ActionResult SaveDraft(FormCollection form)
{
    // TODO: Save the form values and return a JSON result 
    // to indicate if the save went succesfully
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

And in your View just invoke this action periodically:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#theFormToSave').ajaxSubmit({ 
        url    : 'SaveDraft',
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert('form successfully saved');
            }
        }
    });
}, 30000);
```